# MissForest does not work correctly for categorical variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm Implementing Missforest (using Scikit-Learn) for my mixed type data but it doesn't work correctly for my categorical features. For example, 1.6 is replaced for Gender instead of 1 or 0 and doesn't calculate mode for categorical variables.
I have used these lines in python.

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
from missingpy import MissForest
Imputer = MissForest()
X_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your categorical variables first and then use this updated MissForest Algorithm.
https://github.com/HeatherSong/Updated-MissForest-Imputation-Algorithm

Comment: Please don't do  *link only* answers, provide a explanation and use the link just as reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34877545)